# how to post form data to URL in Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have 3 `UITextfield` and 1 Button, when I button click 3 `UITextfield` data sent to the database using forms.

my code is send the data to database but it's show in null values in database.

```
<form action="//http://192.168.3.171:8090/RestWebService/rest/person" id="suggestions" method="post">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" >
    <input id="suggestion"  name="suggestion" type="text">
    <input id="submitsuggestion" name="submitsuggestion" type="text">
</form>
```

Viewcontroller.M

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()
    {


        NSMutableData *recievedData;
        NSMutableData *webData;
        NSURLConnection *connection;
        NSMutableArray *array;
        NSMutableString *first;


    }


    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize webview;
    @synthesize firstName;
    @synthesize lastName;
    @synthesize email;
    - (void)viewDidLoad

    {}


     - (IBAction)send:(id)sender
        {
         NSString *name = firstName.text;
            NSLog(@"  name is %@ ",name);

            NSString *lastname = lastName.text;
            NSLog(@"  name is %@ ",lastname);

            NSString *emailname = email.text;
            NSLog(@"  name is %@ ",emailname);


            if (name.length == 0 || lastname.length == 0 || email.text==0) {
                UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message!" message:@"plz enter 3 fields " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];


                  [alert show];

     }else{
             webData=[NSMutableData data];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.3.128:8050/RestWebService/rest/person"];



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSData *requestData = [@"name=firstName&suggestion=lastName&submitsuggestion=email" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    NSLog(@"requestData%@",requestData);

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

            //[request setValue:requestData forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

            NSLog(@"requestData*******:%@",requestData);

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn)
    {      
        NSLog(@"Connection successfull");
        NSLog(@"GOOD Day My data %@",webData);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"connection could not be made");

    }







    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"DidReceiveResponse");
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"DidReceiveData");
    NSLog(@"DATA %@",data);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error is");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[webData length]);
    NSLog(@"Data is %@",webData);



    // NSLog(@"receivedData%@",_receivedData);

    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseText);//holds textfield entered value

    NSLog(@"");

    NSString *newLineStr = @"\n";
    responseText = [responseText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br />" withString:newLineStr];

    NSLog(@"ResponesText %@",responseText);

   }
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

my `UITextfield` data will be stored in database but it's null.

Comment: form action works only in web page not in app code

Comment: @iDev thanks for reply k but my values stored in database but it's show null values

Comment: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    webd = [NSMutableData data];   
}

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    self.appListData = [NSMutableData data];    // start off with new data
}
```

or

How to pass web service

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"first_name=%@&last_name=%@",firstName.text,lastName.text];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/promos/index.php"]];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if( theConnection ){
    // indicator.hidden = NO;
    mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
```

your PHP code

```
<?php
    $first name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last name=$_POST['last_name'];


    echo $username;
?>
```

Comment: you send username and password values  statical but i want send through my app

Comment: This answer cannot be helpful: you did not percent encode the parameters, and you chose a lossy character conversion. This results likely in corrupted parameters, and possibly to bad query component of the URL. Furthermore, you didn't set the Content-Type header for the request, ... and you didn't mention the most obvious and easiest solution: use JSON as Content-Type ;)

Comment: @iDev You need to ensure that the parameter _values_ are properly _precent encoded_. This makes the strings ASCII characters only. Then, iff this is the case, you can use ASCII encoding to convert the whole query component string to a NSData for use in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Exact answer here for your above Question[FOR POSTING DATA IN YOUR URL(SERVER)]

```
 //Here YOUR URL
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.3.128:8050/RestWebService/rest/person"]];


//create the Method "GET" or "POST"
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Pass The String to server(YOU SHOULD GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS INSTEAD OF MY PARAMETERS)
   NSString *userUpdate =[NSString strin gWithFormat:@"user_email=%@&user_login=%@&user_pass=%@&  last_upd_by=%@&user_registered=%@&",txtemail.text,txtuser1.text,txtpass1.text,txtuser1.text,datestr,nil];



//Check The Value what we passed
   NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

//Convert the String to Data
   NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
   [request setHTTPBody:data1];

//Create the response and Error
   NSError *err;
   NSURLResponse *response;

   NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

   NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response
  NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
  if(resSrt)
   {
     NSLog(@"got response");
  /* ViewController *view =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:NULL];
     [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];*/
   }
  else
   {
     NSLog(@"faield to connect");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make life easy on yourself and use AFNetworking. Instructions for how to post form data are here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking